# SQL's Fallthrough CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In C# we can write

```
switch(num)
{
  case 0:
  case 1: // do something; break;
  case 2:
  ............
  ...........
  case n: // do something break;
  default: //do something; break;
}
```

How can I achieve the similar kind of stuff in SQL SERVER ?

I am not talking about the simple way of writing CASE in SQL SERVER. I am talking about if I need to perform the same king of operation in 2 or more case's as what I showed in C# code snippet, how to do the similar kind of stuff in SQL's CASE?

EDIT:

I got some nice answers from here already. How can I convert the following

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN [A]= num THEN '-' ELSE '' END [A], 
         CASE WHEN [B]= num THEN '-' ELSE '' END [B], 
         CASE WHEN [C]= num THEN '-' ELSE '' END [C],
         CASE WHEN [D]= num THEN '-' ELSE '' END [D]
```

...into something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [A], 
       CASE WHEN [B], 
       CASE WHEN [C], 
       CASE WHEN [D] = num THEN '-' ELSE '' END [A] or [B] or [C] or [D]
```

Actually I need this in a PIVOT query. Last night I solved the problem. But I am not convinced with this way of writing. Because everytime, I am doing the same thing. So is there any better way of presenting this?

Comment: Not sure what behavior you're talking about.  The switch statement you've got (once we add the breaks required to make it compile) maps directly to a simple TSQL case statement.  Try providing some C# that compiles, and whose behavior you want to replicate.

Comment: Note that C#, FWIW, doesn't support fallthrough.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but you could use a logical expression like 'or' in a when statement to introduce multiple conditions dealt with by the same action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for this.

```
SELECT
      CASE 
         WHEN (num BETWEEN 0 AND 2) THEN 'Between 0 and 2'
         WHEN (num = 3) THEN '3'
         ELSE 'Something else'
      END
...
```

[More information on CASE from MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: I understand .. but how put the following into your format

SELECT    CASE WHEN [A]= num THEN '-' ELSE '' END [A]
   ,CASE WHEN [B]= num THEN 'X' ELSE '' END [B]
   ,CASE WHEN [C]= num THEN 'X' ELSE '' END [C]
   ,CASE WHEN [D]= num THEN 'X' ELSE '' END [D]

Comment: I think you've got it as close as you can get it, if you want to return four separate columns.

Answer (score 2):

SQL does support a `CASE` statement but it's not the same thing as the `switch` statement in high level languages like C# and Java. In a switch statement, you have the concept of fall-through where if a `break` statement is not encountered, the flow continues to the next `case`. In contrast, a SQL `CASE` statement behaves like a high level language's `if(value==1){ ... }else if(value==2){ ... }else{ ... }`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I also searched the same in the net but with no answer. So I posted here just to ensure that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This has nothing to do with high level vs. low level, though. And I would even argue that SQL is the higher level language in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Like C# SWITCH statement, SQL Server's CASE **expression** does *not* support fallthrough.

Notice the emphasis on *expression* - it's not to be used for control of flow, use what is [listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174290.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE num
    WHEN 0 THEN ...
    WHEN 1 THEN ...
    ELSE ...
  END as SomeCol
FROM ...
```

Comment: Although - I'm wondering if I'm missing something. In your C# code, you only handle one CASE, just like in this query. If you're wanting procedural code, then you should use IF, but you should try to rework your code into a single query if you can.

Comment: No no.. I am not looking for this.. It is perfect but I want like writing a 1-1 THEN's for a WHEN, can we do something like

CASE num
When 0
When 1 THEN....

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes ..somthing similar to Mr. Hamilton's. To be honest why I need is  last night I was writing a program using PIVOT. Now there I was transforming more than 1 columns and I was converting 1's to '-'. So what I did is, for every case say for 1 or 2 or 3 etc. I wrote the same piece of code. And I felt bad. So I was thinking if there is a better workaround